# SQL Query to Return Top Field for Each Member

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with the following fields...

```
MEMBER_ID (text) 

CATEGORY1 (int) 

CATEGORY2 (int) 

CATEGORY3 (int)

CATEGORY4 (int)
```

...and let's say I have, like, 30+ more CATEGORY fields, all numbered accordingly. And in each category field, there is a numerical score.

Is there a query that could be used to populate a new table that looks like so...

> MEMBER_ID
>
> TOP_CATEGORY (the category name from the previous table with the
>   highest score for this MEMBER_ID)
>
> SECOND_CATEGORY (the category name from the previous table with the
>   second-highest score for this MEMBER_ID)
>
> THIRD_CATEGORY (the category name from the previous table with the
>   third-highest score for this MEMBER_ID)

...I know I could use CASE, but if I have a ton of CATEGORY fields, I assume that would get unwieldy. Do I have any other options?

Comment: A `case` expression is almost impossible if you have ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option in my opinion would be to normalise your database structure. Create a table of members, a table of categories and a table of scores by member & category. Having normalised, the problem you are trying to solve becomes a "top n per group" problem, followed by conditional aggregation. For example, if you follow the template for normalising that I have made in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=34e4476dc69af003b39555abbb336421), your query would look something like this:

```
select member_id,
       max(case when `rank` = 1 then name end) as top_category,
       max(case when `rank` = 2 then name end) as second_category,
       max(case when `rank` = 3 then name end) as third_category
from (select n.member_id, c.name, s1.score, count(s2.score) + 1 as rank
      from score s1
      left join score s2 on s2.member = s1.member and s1.score < s2.score
      join new_members n on n.id = s1.member
      join category c on c.id = s1.category
      group by n.member_id, c.name, s1.score
      having count(s2.score) < 3) s
group by member_id
```

Once your database is normalised, adding new members, categories and scores becomes a lot easier, and queries to get the data out such as the above **don't have to change at all**.

Comment: Thanks! This looks perfect. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible dumb question... For the last query, would I lose anything important if I used something like this? It seems to work roughly the same as your version, but I feel like there's probably something I'm not accounting for...

`select MBR_ID,
max(case when Rank = 1 then name end) as first_category,
max(case when Rank = 2 then name end) as second_category,
max(case when Rank = 3 then name end) as third_category
from Click_Scores
group by MBR_ID`

Comment: @JeffClayton what is `Click_Scores`?

Comment: Ah, sorry... Click_Scores is the table with MBR_ID, NAME, SCORE, and RANK fields.

Comment: @JeffClayton if you've created that table manually then yes, that should work.

Comment: Another follow-up question (and let me preface this by saying how much I appreciate your help): If I were to skip the New_Members table, in which auto-incrementing IDs are assigned to members, would that affect which numbers are assigned to the Rank column a few steps later? Because I'm seeing people with multiple categories with Ranks of 1 (for example), which is causing issues with my final table.

Comment: @JeffClayton the `new_members` table is vital as it is part of the normalisation process. Basically in the normalisation process you are converting the one `members` table into 3 tables - `new_members`, `category` and `score`; that is what allows you to run the subsequent queries. Without those table structures the subsequent queries won't work.